# 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am stuck and I have looked up others solutions to this but I don't quite understand. In my code I have a giant matrix in a csv file that I want to iterate data in my 4th column only. It is called 'MovementTime' i thought that by calling it the way shown below I could iterate my data and therefore sort it. I am getting the error

> 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Can someone explain to me why im getting this error?

Thank you!

```
bigdata = pd.read_csv(r'Assetslog_912021_11.csv')
data = pd.DataFrame(bigdata)

#create a function to analyze data


def analytics(data):
    data.columns = ['Time', 'Fixed Delta', 'Movement Time', 'MovementNumber', 'Rest Flag', 'DistortionDigit', 'RobotForceX','RobotForceY','RobotForceZ', 'PrevPositionX','PrevPositionY','PrevPositionZ', 'TargetPosZ', 'TargetPosY', 'TargetPosZ', 'PlayerPosX', 'PlayerPosX', 'PlayerPosY', 'PlayerPosZ', 'RobotVelX','RobotVelY','RobotVelZ', 'LocalPosX', 'LocalPosY', 'LocalPosZ', 'PerpError', 'ExtError']  
    i = np.iterable(data.columns)
    for i in set(data['MovementNumber'.]):
        print("Plot for Movement Number " + str(i))
        data2 = data.loc[['MovementNumber'] == i]
    ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
    xdata = data2['PlayerPosX'].values
    ydata = data2['PlayerPosY'].values
    zdata = data2['PlayerPosZ'].values
    plot1 =ax.scatter3D(xdata,ydata,zdata, c=zdata)
    plt.show(plot1)
```

Comment: the cause of the error is basically you doing this: `'some string'.values` (although most probably it is more like `var = 'some string'; var.values`) so looking at your code it seems that `data2['PlayerPosX']` and the like are a string

Comment: `data2` is going to be one row.  `data2['PlayerPosX']` is going to be one single value.  Were you expecting `data2` to be multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

This line is not right:

```
       data2 = data.loc[['MovementNumber'] == i]
```

That's going to compare a list containing a string to an integer, which will always be false.  I believe you want

```
       data2 = data[data['MovementNumber'] == i]]
```

That assigns to `data2` all the rows where MovementNumber  is `i`.

And, by the way, your indentation is wrong.  I assume you want one plot per movement number, so all the lines starting with `ax = ...` need to be indented, so they are inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks! I am still getting the hang of python but that helped and I appreciate it. I wish python wasn't finicky about indentation, haha. :)

Comment: That's one of its best features.  No more { } begin/end.